# Jupyter : [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I got the error while running a code:

```
[WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'E:\\PlantVillage/Pepper__bell___Bacterial_spot/0022d6b7-d47c-4ee2-ae9a-392a53f48647___JR_B.Spot 8964.JPG/'
```

I'm ruuning the code on jupyter notebook with python 3.8

The root directory is:

```
directory_root = "E:\PlantVillage"
```

The code is:

```
image_list, label_list = [], []
try:
    print("[INFO] Loading images ...")
    root_dir = listdir(directory_root)
    for directory in root_dir :
        # remove .DS_Store from list
        if directory == ".DS_Store" :
            root_dir.remove(directory)

    for plant_folder in root_dir :
        plant_disease_folder_list = listdir(f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}")

        for disease_folder in plant_disease_folder_list :
            # remove .DS_Store from list
            if disease_folder == ".DS_Store" :
                plant_disease_folder_list.remove(disease_folder)

        for plant_disease_folder in plant_disease_folder_list:
            print(f"[INFO] Processing {plant_disease_folder} ...")
            plant_disease_image_list = listdir(f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}/{plant_disease_folder}/")

            for single_plant_disease_image in plant_disease_image_list :
                if single_plant_disease_image == ".DS_Store" :
                    plant_disease_image_list.remove(single_plant_disease_image)

            for image in plant_disease_image_list[:200]:
                image_directory = f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}/{plant_disease_folder}/{image}"
                if image_directory.endswith(".jpg") == True or image_directory.endswith(".JPG") == True:
                    image_list.append(convert_image_to_array(image_directory))
                    label_list.append(plant_disease_folder)
    print("[INFO] Image loading completed")  
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error : {e}")
```

The directory on Windows is, which can be seen in the image attached:

```
"E:\PlantVillage\Pepper__bell___Bacterial_spot\0022d6b7-d47c-4ee2-ae9a-392a53f48647___JR_B.Spot 8964.JPG"
```

[image]

Comment: pls review this line, for forward and backward slashes based on your os. `image_directory = f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}/{plant_disease_folder}/{image}"` or use generic logic to join paths. `root="one"
next_1="next"
os.path.join(root,next_1)` or join by using `my_paths=['root','subfolder',"subsubfolder"]
os.path.join(*my_paths)`

Comment: Your program structure does not match your folder structure on drive E:. The example pictures are located two levels deep (PlantVillage, then plant disease), while your program assumes three levels (..., plant, then plant disease). The error message is because there's an illegal `/` at the end of the filename. I think the error lies with the line `plant_disease_image_list = listdir(f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}/{plant_disease_folder}/")`. If only this would be a Minimum Viable Runnable Example...

Answer (score 0):

So after "E:\PlantVillage" create another folder(name it as you wish) and cut all the folders present in the "PlantVillge" and paste it in the new folder you have created
(Eg before "E:\PlantVillage\Pepper__bell__Bacterial_spot" to "E:\PlantVillage\NewFolder\Pepper__bell__Bacterial_spot"

Answer (score 0):

- So if you getting this that mean directory_root is correct
  if not:
  make sure you are one step=>{./} or two step{..?} back try both
  else:
  firstly
  perform this in separate box=>

  import os

  then in second box

  plant_disease_image_list=['directory_root','plant_folder',"plant_disease_folder"]
  os.path.join(*plant_disease_image_list)

  Copy this!!!